# Dysfunctional IRF9540

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gNLF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to build my own SMPS and I was intending on using a P-Channel MOSFET for high side driving the main circuit. The MOSFET in question is the IRF9540. It is rated for continuous (worst case) 18Amps but when I draw 2 amps, it stays closed forever and a component tester no longer sees it as a P-Channel MOSFET but now two resistors. I have kept the Vgs in limit a long with Vds. Is this something I am doing wrong or are my MOSFETS bad (I did buy them from AliExpress but they don't look fake.) Could a too high frequency damage it?

Within the schematic treat the op-amp as a comparator.
Also, I am aware that this hysterectic power supply is not ideal, however, I will be changing to a PWM control.

---

Update:

I have solved the issue. I have now changed the entire circuit to that it had an opamp controlling a PWM duty cycle fixed at 4kHz. I have achieved 5A of current draw. Thank you for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Schematics are much better than words. Add one in. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar that's easy to use.

Comment: If it "shows up as *two* resistors", you've blown the gate, probably through poor handling practices. You'll have to be a lot more careful with the next one.

Comment: _"I did buy them from AliExpress but they don't look fake."_ - Maybe the counterfeiters did a really good job on the exterior ;)

Comment: Thanks for adding your new schematic, which solves the **original** question. However, you also added **new** questions about PWM. Please don't do that - it should be one topic per question, otherwise it makes the question muddled. Therefore I have "rolled-back" (i.e. reverted) the question back to the version before your changes today, and just added your comment and new schematic. Please ask a new question (you can copy the new schematic and text, from the edit history of this question). You can add a link in the new question back to this one, so people can see the history. See what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Does your setup includes a pull up resistor?
Does your setup includes a current limiting resistor to the gate?

Having the gate directly connected to a logic output might have created transients (current and/or voltage) due to the MOSFET's gate capacitance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have solved the issue. I have now changed the entire circuit to that it had an opamp controlling a PWM duty cycle fixed at 4kHz. I have achieved 5A of current draw. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I am glad to hear that! Would you mind sharing the improved circuit? Just as a reference if people with similar issues end up here. Also I am a bit curious.

Comment: @benguru - FYI, the updated schematic from the OP is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs4q0.png). You can see in my comments on the question itself, that adding more new questions today made the topic muddled. So I've removed the new questions and I've recommended that the new questions about that new schematic, are asked as a new topic.